# Renew Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning

Just got a notice that the provisioning profile for one of my apps is about to expire. Is there some way I can renew the existing one or must I recreate a new one?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For renew team provisioning profile managed by Xcode :

In the organizer of Xcode :

- Right click on your device (in the left list)
- Click on "Add device to provisioning portal"
- Wait until it's done !

Comment: NB, I had to delete the soon-to-be-expired provisioning profile from the device first.

Comment: This technique is not working for me this morning. I get as far as "Listing Teams" and then a pop-up tells me "Request Timed-out"

Comment: I don't know what fixed it for me, but yes. I think I upgraded xCode or something. Sorry I can't be more precise...

Comment: For a company that is famous for intuitiveness (if that's a word) this is extremely hidden and obscure. Worked for me, it did also prompt me something else relating to the provisioning profile and asked if xcode should fetch it for me, I said yes and it worked.

Comment: How to renew provisioning profile for device which is not near you, plugged into mac?

Comment: This option no longer exists

Comment: This answer is out of date -- the option is no longer there.

Comment: Here's what I did: (1) within Xcode 14.2 = Settings **->** sign in if required **->** Manage Certificates **->** Click **+** in lower left corner to add a new Development Certificate which will be good for just **1 week** (2) before that 7-day period expires, return to your Project, select your Target **->** "Signing and Capabilities" **->** "Automatically Manage Signing" which will allow Xcode to create/update Profiles, App IDs, and Certificates. DONE!

Answer (score 24):

I went to the Program Portal on Apple's dev site, clicked on Provisioning, clicked on the "Renew" button next to my Profile, the status changed from 'expired' to 'pending', waited a few moments, clicked refresh, the new status was active until 3 months from now, I clicked on "Download", found the downloaded file in my downloads folder, and dragged it onto my XCode Icon. (I had Xcode running already, and had the iphone plugged in). The new profile showed up, and I deleted the old one (being careful because they had the same name, but when you mouse over them the expiration date appears).

I think because I had the phone plugged in already it automagically updated to the phone, because I didn't have to re-sync or anything.

Now my App works again!

Comment: I don't have a renew button next to my expired profile.  What does that mean?  How do I renew it?

Comment: I don't know. This may have changed since I did it nearly two years ago.

Comment: if the main certificate expired you first have to regenerate that then edit each expired profile and submit it with the new certificate

Comment: Under Provisioning > Distrubution. I also don't have any "Renew" buttons. My distribution certificate is valid. I dunno what to do?

Comment: No longer accurate... At this point, best to remove this answer

Answer (score 14):

I've done what you suggest, and I don't see a "Renew" button either.

The following is how I got mine renewed.

I see my three profiles (companynameProfile, "Team Provisioning Profile", and productnameProfile).  THe first and third are going to expire within a couple of weeks.
The second (and only the second) is flagged as "managed by Xcode".  The profile names
appear in a table with columns labelled: "Provisioning Profile", App ID, Status, and Actions.
The status for all three is "Active".  First 1 and 3, the Actions column has a "Download"
button, and an "Edit" link.  For 2, gthe Actions column has only the "Download" button.

There is no "Renew" (or "Refresh") button / link anywhere (and I did a view-source and searched that too :)

So, I thought...click on "Edit" on #3 ... two choices pop-up: Modify and Duplicate.
I chose "Modify"

There is still no renew/refresh ... but there is a "Submit" button ... which doesn't
work (turns out its sort of grayed out, but that's not at all obvious...bad UI design).

I discovered that if I change something on the screen (in my case, I selected a previously
unused device), "Submit" darkens (becomes available).
Click on "Submit".
You're quietly (another UI problem :) taken back to the prior page, and the
"Download" and "Edit" buttons are gone, and the status column should say "Pending"!

After awhile, I refreshed the window (reloaded) (don't know if it would have
auto-refreshed) ... and saw that the status column had changed to "Active".

Now...I downloaded the new profile (the one that the darn page doesn't *tell* you is new,
and doesn't *LIST THE EXPIRATION DATE* so you could tell yourself ... third UI flaw already :)

I downloaded the profile, deleted the old profile from the list in the Organizer window of Xcode, then dragged the new one into the Organizer window of Xcode, and ... voila, Organizer shows a new expiration date (of about 3 months from today).

Hope that helps,

Stan
Cupertino, CA, USA

Comment: In my case I had a Distrubution Provisioning Profile that was expired. The way I renewed it was to choose "Modify" and then from the "App ID" popupbutton select a wrong item, and then select the original App ID again. Then I was able to press the Submit button.

Answer (score 9):

As of May 2017 this process seems to have changed yet again (a bit).

I did not find it necessary to actually modify anything to do with my profile, and fortunately the certificate was still valid so renewal ended up being a simple process though figuring out exactly **what** to do was not straightforward.

1. Select the expiring profile in your developer account and click "Edit"
   [image: Select Expiring Profile and Edit]
2. Click the "Generate" button

   - Verify that the certificate linked to the profile is still valid for at least a year
   - I did not find it necessary to modify the profile in any way
     [image: Click Generate Button]
3. On the next screen, verify that the expiration date of the profile has been extended
   [image: Verify extended expiration date]

Comment: How do I access the screen in step 1? I assume this is somewhere on the developer website..

Comment: @galactikuh you'll need to sign in to developer.apple.com and then select "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" and find the profile that needs renewing

Comment: Looks like my account expired, which would explain why I can't see it.

Comment: Do you need to pay to get this now?  Everything I try to do on developer.apple.com just funnels me through to the page where you buy the developer program membership for £79... but I was able to originally set up the profile without membership, so has this changed?

Comment: @Jules same for me.

Comment: @galactikuh - I did get it working in the end. Had to completely remove the account information from the provisioning section of the organizer and then add it back in, and that made it renew correctly.

Answer (score 8):

Do you know if the renew button only appeared when the profile expired? I've a profile that will expire soon, but no "renew" button is shown at the moment.

Just read elsewhere that apparently this is the case.

Comment: in typical apple 'user-friendly' fashion, it seems the renew option only becomes available after expiration.

Comment: That is not true, you simply download a new profile at any point in time and you have a new expiry date.

Comment: That didn't work for me when I tried just now; the provisioning profiles have the same expiration date.  (I even deleted the old ones from Xcode's Organizer and then dragged the new ones in; no joy.)

Comment: ...however, I WAS able to get new expiration dates by choosing Edit, making some change (like unchecking the checkbox for a device), and submitting.

Answer (score 7):

They've changed it now. (Oct 2010)

1. Log into iPhone developer website: http://developer.apple.com/
2. Then click on "Provisioning Portal" on the right hand sidebar menu (right at the top).
3. On the next page click "Provisioning" in the left sidebar menu
4. Then you'll see your provisioning profile/s, and the 'renew' button/s - Press it :)

Answer (score 3):

Update March 2013

The expiry date of the provisioning profile is linked to the expiry date of the developer certificate. And I didn't want to wait for it to expire so here is what I did -

- Go to the [iOS Provisioning portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/distribute.action)
- Revoke the current certificate
- In Xcode > Organizer go to the Provisioning profiles page (under Library)
- Press refresh and it will prompt you to create a new developer certificate
  since the current one has been revoked
- Follow the steps to create one
- Go back to the [iOS provisioning portal for your distribution profiles](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/viewDistributionProfiles.action) and change something about it so it will enable the submit button.
- Submit it and the date of the new certificate will get applied to it

Comment: I too had a provisioning profile expiring in 12 days that was linked to a certificate that also was expiring in 12 days. Using the above steps allowed Xcode to regenerate the certificate that I revoked. I then had to re-link my distribution provisioning profiles with the new certificate. All is good.

Comment: typical bloody apple, they are always changing the way stuff works

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work anymore.  I have a project being managed (still) on XCode 4.6.3, and the Refresh button in the Organizer no longer gets it's requests serviced by apple.  When you hit the button, it says "Service Unavailable" so.... thanks apple.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode4 go to the Organizer. Choose at library the Provisioning Profiles. Select your provisioning profile and click on the "Refresh" button at the bottom. It will ask you to enter your login and password. After that, the profile is renewed.

Answer (score 2):

They change how this works so often.  This is what I had to do this time (May 2016):

- Add a new provisioning profile in the Developer Member Center
- Open XCode preferences, Account > Choose Apple ID > Choose Team Name > View Details
- Click the Download button in the Action column for the newly-created provisioning profile

Answer (score 1):

To renew the development profile before it expired, I finally found a way that works for me. I boldfaced the steps I had been missing before.

Go to the Apple provisioning portal, select "Provisioning". You'll get a list "Development Provisioning Profiles" where you'll see your soon to expire profile with the label "Managed by XCode". Click the **"New Profile"** button on top, select the type of profile you want and create it. Wait half a minute, refresh the home screen and when it shows the new profile as "Active", switch back to XCode, go to the Organizer, select "Provisioning profiles" under "Library" in left top column. Click "Refresh" at the bottom, log in (if it asks) and the new profile appears in the list after a short while.

Now, crucially, connect your device and **drag your new profile** to the "Provisioning Profiles" row under the connected device in the left column.

Finally, you can clean up the old profiles from your device if you feel like it.

*Note: interestingly, it seems that simply marking and deleting your provisioning profile on the iOS Provisioning Portal site causes a new fresh Team Provisioning Profile to be created. So maybe that is all that is needed. I will try that next time to see if that is enough, if so you don't need to create a profile as I described above.*

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other solutions I needed to edit the code signing on the main project and the Target file to get the app building to the device again after an expired provisioning profile.

::Delete the old expired profiles

::Add the new profile with the Organizer

::Clean All Targets

::Get Info -> Code Signing on both the main project and the Target

::Build and Run

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately renewing does not seem to work in my case. My Ad Hoc Distribution Profile is about to expire in 5 days. I got warnings about that on the iPhone and the Xcode Organizer shows a warning sign next to it as well.

In Apple's provisioning portal it was marked as inactive and there was a button to reactivate it. But still with the same expiry date, 5 days from now. 
Next, I added two more iPhones to it, yet, the changed profile still expires 5 days from now.

Finally, I deleted the profile in the provisioning portal and created a new one from scratch, using a different name, yet this new one still expires on April 13th, 5 days from now!

That is really frustrating! So I guess I have to wait until after it expires and create a new one then.

In case you are wondering if my developer subscription runs out, it is not. I just renewed it in February.

Answer (score 1):

for Team Profile, simple in Prereference --> Account--->select the corret account-->detail-->click the left bottom 'refresh' button. the profile will be renewed.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was occurring because there was no active Production certificate. I created a new one, and then went to the expired distribution provisioning profile, added the certificate and the provisioning profile got activated.

Comment: Atul, is it possible that my one month old provisioning profile expired because its certificate expired? Am I right that you had the same issue? I've made a provisioning profile for distribution a month ago, and it has been expired yesterday, but I don't have an idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are outdated here. Your provisioning profile connects to your certificate. It's expiry date is determined by the certificate's expiry. So to do this manually, follow the steps to update your certificate and edit your provisioning profile and select the new certificate. Your provisioning will change its expiration to the certs expiry date. If my answer needs more details drop a comment and I can fill it out a bit more.

The steps I won't cover here in detail are 1. generating code signing manually, as this is covered in many places. What you want is a development certificate and a distribution certificate. This should be added to your Mac's keychain and be visible in `https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list` . 2. you need to have set up your identifiers which are your bundle ids and your capabilities.

If you need to run development builds on devices you will have to add these to your devices tab. https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list . Again, I will not cover this.

So, now if your provisioning is outdated because your certs are out of date simply regenerate your certs. Once you do this you can go to your profiles list `https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list` . Find the profile you need to update and open it. Select edit, and scroll down to `Certificates` and find the valid certs. Deselect the invalid ones and select the valid ones. Select/deselect any devices if you're in the development provisioning.

[image]

Next save this and download. Find provisioning at `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`. You can try to delete the old one by inspecting the ones you have there using https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL/releases/tag/1.6.2 this quicklooks plugin. Double tap the profile after downloading it will add it to this folder or you can drag it there. Now try to archive and make sure everything is working.

Incidently your profiles can become invalid for other reasons too, for example if you change the capabilities of your app. If you open a provisioning profile from developer.apple.com it will say whether it's valid or not under `Status` right at the top.

Comment: It's very unhelpful to say "follow the steps". The whole point of questions like this is that people don't know what the steps are.

Comment: @Alex If you asked respectfully I'd be happy to add to my post as I state in the last sentence!

Comment: @SmileBot Respectfully, please add the steps to which you refer, thanks!

Comment: @reformed Ok, I added some details. Please leave feedback as I'm not sure which parts you are struggling with.

Comment: @SmileBot thanks, much appreciated. I'm amazed at how ridiculously and unnecessarily convoluted Apple is. This further confirms my hatred of all things Apple

Comment: @reformed I accidently discovered that when you get the message to update your provisioning profiles you actually don't change the profiles except to point them to the new certs. Once you have that piece of information it's pretty easy to figure it out. I never came across that and that's why I posted my solution. Cheers.