# After renewing my iPhone Developer Program account, must I do the whole provisioning profile stuff again?

Tags: iphone

Which parts must I redo after renewing my iPhone Dev Program account?

My devices tell me that my provisioning profiles are out of date. So now I must go there and do the entire stuff again? Also that certificate in the key chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I run into a provisioning profile expiration, I turn to Craig Hockenberry's great [article on the subject](http://furbo.org/2009/01/12/expiration-perspiration/).  I believe that some aspects of the provisioning center have been updated to improve this process, but it still stands as a good guide.  See also the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342497/renew-provisioning-profile).

Answer (score 1):

Naw, you just need to renew your dev prov profile, download and assign it in your project again.

because the AppID is the same (and the distro profile hasn't expired), it won't mess up your distribution process.

Comment: ha ha ... wrong. That doesn't work. I had to uninstall EVERYTHING, make new AppID and the whole entire thing completely from scratch. Xcode refused to accept anything until I did so.