# ios Provisioning Profile renewal

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

My Provisioning Profiles for iPhone have just expired and I cannot download anything to my test device for testing anymore.  Have tired "Automatic Device Provisioning (Refresh)", the Team Provisioning Profile seemed to have updated in the process.  But my profile on a specific software in development cannot be extended similarly.  Hope somebody who have experience on this could help ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renew Provisioning Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342497/renew-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your device using the Xcode Organizer window.  Delete any expired provisions from the device and install the same non-expired provision as specified in your Target build settings for whichever of your your Debug or Release builds you are trying to run.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Somehow when I run xcode again, everything seems to be ok.  And when I check the organizer, the expired provisions are not there anymore.  So I think you must be right, the expired provisions need to be deleted if they are still present.  Just that I was afraid to delete anything just in case the files are needed and could not be brought back. Thanks ...