# Can we extend the expire date of a provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

In my iPhone app, I have a functionality to check the reminders and validate the future dates.

While changing the dates (future dates like 2013) to from settings of an iPhone,
App shows me an Error message that your provisioning profile for this app has been expired.

So, could not check further dates. So, How can I modify my provisioning profile to extend the expiry date of an profile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renew Provisioning Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342497/renew-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 0):

From memory i believe you have to ask apple for a new provisioning profile, but im not sure