# iOS Code Signing Identity

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

My Xcode 4.6 iOS project has "PROJECT" and "TARGETS" sections, each of which has a "Debug" and "Release" area under "Code Signing Identity" with an "Any iOS SDK" entry.

1. Currently, I specify my Developer or Distribution provisioning
   profile in all four of the slots under PROJECT and TARGET. I believe
   that each provisioning profile really only needs to be placed in one
   position.
2. Whenever I update a provisioning profile because it is expiring, I
   am adding additional development devices, or I am adding additional
   AdHoc test devices, it is always painful. Xcode never allows me to
   simply choose "iPhone Developer". I always have to navigate to the
   correct provisioning profile by name. Furthermore, I have to delete
   the old provisioning profiles before I import the new ones,
   otherwise the old ones will continue to get used.

It all looks something like this:

```
PROJECT
    myProject
        Code Signing
            Code Signing Identity
                Debug               iPhone Developer
                    Any iOS SDK     iPhone Developer
                Release             iPhone Distribution
                    Any iOS SDK     iPhone Distribution
TARGET
    myTarget
        Code Signing
                Debug               iPhone Developer
                    Any iOS SDK     iPhone Developer
                Release             iPhone Distribution
                    Any iOS SDK     iPhone Distribution
```

So, here are my summarized questions:

1. On which line should I specify the provisioning profile?
2. What is the best way to import an updated provisioning profile into
   Xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1. On which line should I specify the provisioning profile?
```

Firstly, you are not obliged to set provisioning profiles in the `PROJECT` section. I always set them in the `TARGET` section. Now if your are developing, you should set the:

```
Any iOS SDK     iPhone Developer
```

Under `Debug`. And if you are preparing Adhoc, you need to set:

```
Any iOS SDK     iPhone Distribution
```

Under `Release`.

```
2 .What is the best way to import an updated provisioning profile into Xcode?
```

Go to `Organizer`, click `Devices` tab, then hit the `New` button at the bottom, you will be prompted to sign in your Apple account. Then I think profiles will be imported, click `Refresh` button to see added profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about "PROJECT". I have removed settings from there and up voted. By "Any iOS SDK" do you mean I should remove the duplicate setting from the "Debug" and "Release" lines? Unfortunately, by import with the Organizer "+" button or double-click on the Provisioning Profile in the finder, it continues to use the old one. Wondering how to get around that? Any ideas?

Comment: No, you can keep them. Make sure that the `Any iOS SDK` line is updated as I said. For renewing profile, refer to this thread, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342497/renew-provisioning-profile Cheers :)